# Rigging stretches my model

Tags: rigging, armature

Totally new to Blender and I am stuck here.  I rigged my model with an armature by going into object mode, clicking the model, and then shift clicking the bones.  Then pressing Ctrl-A, and selecting automatic weights...It connects to my model, but when I try to move one of the bones, it basically picks a point and will move that, but not the rest of the model.  I'm sure I'm doing something basic, but I have researched a bunch and can't seem to find the answer.  Can someone help me?  Here's a screenshot.
Thanks!
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using an unapplied Skin modifier, right?

So the "real mesh", the one who receive the automatic weights from the armature it's actually made of a bunch of vertices, the ones that they are moved. The problem is all here: the vertices created by the skin modifier aren't affected by the armature because they don't really exist yet.

You can try to move the skin modifier to the bottom of the list, so it will occour after the armature deformation, but to get nice an smooth deformations, you'll have to provide more "real" vertices to the mesh. You can for example subdifide your skeleton or apply the skin modifier.

Comment: You were right on spot.  Thanks a lot Carlo, I am new to this, so the issue may have been obvious, but you really helped me out a lot.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Carlo. I just posted a similar question and that is exactly what my issue was. I messed up on another spot which created two Armature skins. One of them was at the top (broken), but my correct one was at the very bottom. Once I deleted the wrong one and moved the Armature to the top it fixed it for me.[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  The image helped me understand what you were talking about!